# How to change Special Price color in Magento

Tags: magento

I'm currently using Magento 1.7.0.2

I'm trying to change SPECIAL price color from grey to more catchy color like Red or Orange.

In the system-Configuration-Design I saw the current Package is default, Themes Templates are called Blanco,  exceptions for mobiles iphone etc are called: blancoresponsive

So I changed the file in skin/frontend/default/blanco/css/styles.css 
find codes

```
.special-price .price-label { font-size:11px; text-transform:uppercase; white-space:nowrap; color:#000; }
.special-price .price { font-size:16px; }
```

I changed to

```
.special-price .price-label { font-size:11px; text-transform:uppercase; white-space:nowrap; color:#cd5033; }
.special-price .price { font-size:16px; color:#cd5033; }
```

After flush magento cache and cache storage, price doesn't change.

After that i tried to change styles.css from other theme files like default, and blancoresponsive, and there is another theme file called blanco_bk
Anyway nothing works it still shows black.

Anyway know what went wrong?
Thanks

Comment: Have you checked which rules are actually applying to the special price elements?

Comment: Hi thank you i think i find out why. I want to change special price color in category page, this is to change in product page. Thanx anyway

Answer (score 0):

Go to skin/frontend/yourtheme/default/css/styles.css

in styles.css

about line 806

```
/* Old price */
.old-price { margin:0; }
.old-price .price-label { font-size:12px; font-weight:bold; white-space:nowrap; }
/*.old-price .price { font-weight:bold; font-size:13px; color:#396f00; text-decoration:line-through; }*/
.old-price .price {
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:13px;
    color:#333;
    text-decoration:line-through;
}

/* Special price */
.special-price { margin:0; }
.special-price .price-label { font-size:11px; font-weight:bold; text-transform:uppercase; white-space:nowrap; color:#000; }
.special-price .price {
    font-size:13px;
    font-weight:bold;
    color: #C00;
}
```

Comment: Hi Thank you so much. I just figured out why it doesn't work, what i wanted was actually special price colored in category page, this code is to change the color in product page. Thanx anyway.